# How to access the heartrate meter on a glaxy phone without the Samsung Health app?

Tags: android

I use an old Samsung Galaxy phone. I'd like to use the inbuilt heartrate sensor, which can be accessed with the Samsung Health app. However I don't use the tracking/recording anyway I don't want any data sharing. Is there another app that lets me access this sensor?

So far I've tried the physics sensor toolsuit (no).